# service worker not operating correctly?

Tags: javascript

So I have this service worker which I added to my site to make it work offline:

```
var version = 'v1::';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration in progress.');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function() {
        // console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration complete.');
    }, function() {
        // console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration failure.');
    });
} else {
    // console.log('CLIENT: service worker is not supported.');
}

self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {
    console.log('WORKER: install event in progress.');
    event.waitUntil(

        caches

        .open(version)
        .then(function(cache) {


            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/data',
                '/images',
                '/design.css',
                '/map.js',
                '/function.js',
                '/index.html',
                '/compare.html',
                '/stock.html',
                '/selection.html',
                '/mapImages',
                '/compare.js',
                '/manifest.webmanifest.json',
                '/game.html'
            ]);
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('WORKER: install completed');
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    console.log('WORKER: fetch event in progress.');
    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
        return;
    }

    event.respondWith(
        caches

        .match(event.request)
        .then(function(cached) {
            var networked = fetch(event.request)

                .then(fetchedFromNetwork, unableToResolve)

                .catch(unableToResolve);

            return cached || networked;

            function fetchedFromNetwork(response) {

                var cacheCopy = response.clone();

                console.log('WORKER: fetch response from network.', event.request.url);

                caches
                    .open(version + 'pages')
                    .then(function add(cache) {
                        cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('WORKER: fetch response stored in cache.', event.request.url);
                    });

                return response;
            }

            function unableToResolve() {
                return new Response('<h1>This page does not exist</h1>', {
                    status: 503,
                    statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    })
                });
            }
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {

    console.log('WORKER: activate event in progress.');

    event.waitUntil(
        caches

        .keys()
        .then(function(keys) {

            return Promise.all(
                keys
                .filter(function(key) {

                    return !key.startsWith(version);
                })
                .map(function(key) {

                    return caches.delete(key);
                })
            );
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log('WORKER: activate completed.');
        })
    );
});
```

What I'm concerned about is the way it works.
When testing with dev tools, sometimes the app works offline and other times it doesn't. Also I've tested my site on the mobile and for some reason while not using wifi it doesn't work offline.

So I'm wondering there's something wrong with my code or if there's something I'm missing or don't need.

any advice would be great, I might not perfectly know how to use them but this is my best attempt.